# Changing the ForeignKey based on choices

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a Model that has a field with choices like:

```
MANUFACTURER_CHOICES = (
        ('Commscope', 'Commscope'),
        ('Corning', 'Corning'),
        ('SOLiD', 'SOLiD'),
        ('Cisco', 'Cisco'),
        ('DIGI', 'DIGI')
    )    

manufacturer = models.CharField(
        max_length=9,
        choices=MANUFACTURER_CHOICES
    )
```

But I want the choice to actually be a ForeignKey, impacting the data and fields that are being referenced.

i.e. If Commscope is picked, it attaches the Commscope Model to the Device Model. If Cisco is picked, the Cisco Model and so on and so forth.

Comment: Well then you create a model `Manufacturer`, and you override the `__str__` such that the name (or another relevant attribute) shows up. You can then use migrations (for example) to "populate" the database with predefined choices.

Comment: Your based on your question, you want to define different *models*?

Comment: I'd like to define multiple models - each Manufacturer Choice would preferably be a specific model.

Comment: a *model*, or an *object*. Using different models is strictly speaking possible, but then this will typically result in a lot of trouble: since there is no type attached to such `GenericForeignKey`, you can not make use of Django's advanced ORM features like querying on the attributes/relations of that `GenericForeignKey`, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to reference a Tuple of objects as my choices in the CharField?